# Making text readable with python plus opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have to make this picture more readable by denoising it and increasing the contrast. I think I am done with the denoising part, because the lines have disappeared, but now some parts of the text (where the lines were) are missing. Can you help me solving this?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('noised.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

alpha = 2.5
beta = 0.0

denoised = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

cv2.imshow('before', img)
cv2.imshow('after', denoised)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- The image before denoising:

[image: before]

- The image after denoising:

[image: after]